# How to re-create a Microsoft Access application to a WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an existing MS access application for capturing information (normal add, edit forms with drop downs and so-forth) that I'd like to redesign into a WPF C# application using a Microsoft SQL database.

My question is, is WPF the easiest / quickest solution or are there any alternatives anyone can suggest?

I have some knowledge of WPF and a good understanding of SQL databases.

Thanks

Comment: When you have a good knowledge in WPF, why not ?

Comment: @shaunfocus Since you have some knowledge of WPF, differentiate WPF with WinForms, as an alternative, you should draw a conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your application is data driven so as an "easy but not so far" alternative to WPF I would suggest you to have a look at Visual Studio LightSwitch. It is especially designed to quickly create data driven screens with full CRUD hosted within Silverlight (desktop) or within HTML5 (web).

Silverlight is quite dead but it will be easy for you to jump on if you are already familiar with WPF.

Have a look here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oIBJrGp-kOY